What is the physical interpretation of the eigenvalues of the Maxwell stress tensor?
The Wikipedia page on Maxwell stress tensor has a section on the eigenvalues of the Maxwell stress tensor, which is given by
$$ \mathrm{Eig}\{\mathbf{T}\} = \left\{ -\left(\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2\right), \pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2-\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2\right)^2 + \frac{\epsilon_0}{\mu_0}\left(\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B}\right)^2} \right\}. $$
However, the Wikipedia page linked to only tells us how to derive such an equation. My question is, how should we interpret this expression? Is there some sort of "eigenvalue equation" for the tensor, with its set of eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Are you familiar with the concept of principal stresses?

No. My knowledge on continuum dynamics is sadly quite limited.
